# How to move content from lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, twitter-bootstrap, hybrid-mobile-app

Iv'e been working on this for a while now and need the help. Currently I have 2 lists with content in. I want to be able to select content from one list and move it into the second list. To do this I want to be able to select one or multiple content and then click a button which moves the content. I can't get the actual move function working. The code I have is from an example I found on the internet "http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/" and is the second example.

**Here is my 2 lists and button code**:

```
  <div class="btn-group buttons">
    <button title="Move selected" type="button" class="btn move btn-default" "demo2"></button>
  </div>
  <select style="height: 197px;" name="duallistbox_demo2_helper1" class="form-control" id="bootstrap-duallistbox-nonselected-list_duallistbox_demo2" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
    <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
    <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
    <option value="option0">Option 10</option>
    <option value="option0">Option 11</option>
    <option value="option0">Option 12</option>
  </select>


  <div class="btn-group buttons">     
  <button title="Remove selected" type="button" class="btn remove btn-default"></button>     
  </div>
  <select style="height: 197px;" name="duallistbox_demo2_helper2" class="form-control" id="bootstrap-duallistbox-selected-list_duallistbox_demo2" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
  <option value="option4">Option 4</option></select>
```

**Here is my JS**:

```
// move list content
var demo2 = $('.demo2').bootstrapDualListbox({
  nonSelectedListLabel: 'Non-selected',
  selectedListLabel: 'Selected',
  preserveSelectionOnMove: 'moved',
  moveOnSelect: false,
  nonSelectedFilter: 'ion ([7-9]|[1][0-2])'
});
```

Comment: Hi @TheGarrett, please check [GITHUB](https://github.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/bootstrap-duallistbox/blob/master/demo/index.html)

Comment: Checked it from the strart... wher eI got the JS from

Comment: problem with your code is that you have used wrong syntax for class ```class="btn move btn-default" "demo2"``` , it should be ```class="btn move btn-default demo2"```.

Comment: Still have the same problem to the previous comment on the first answer

Answer (score 0):

following js should work for your first select box. pls make sure are selecting proper element.

```
var demo2 = $('#bootstrap-duallistbox-nonselected-list_duallistbox_demo2').bootstrapDualListbox({
  nonSelectedListLabel: 'Non-selected',
  selectedListLabel: 'Selected',
  preserveSelectionOnMove: 'moved',
  moveOnSelect: false,
  nonSelectedFilter: 'ion ([7-9]|[1][0-2])'
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I can only select 1 item from the list but selecting multiple content and the move function still doesn't work